# use of distinct in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

can anyone tell me how can I select unique fruit_name along with person_id
I write query but it gives error.

My query:

```
select person_id,distinct fruit_name from person_fruit;
```

Table:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's `SELECT DISTINCT`, and it works on the whole selected rows.

Comment: You have two different mango rows. Can you explain which person_id you want in this case?

Comment: any person_id i can take...is there another way to get result

Comment: So just 2 or 4, it doesn't matter which one?

Comment: no it doesn't matter..but need one of them

Comment: Just do the GROUP BY, as in dnoeth's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DISTINCT` always works on all columns. In Standard SQL it must be placed directly after `SELECT` (in fact the default is `SELECT ALL`), your syntax is not valid Standard SQL.

You must define which of the ids you want to return as there are multiple ids per fruit.

In your case you can simply switch to a GROUP BY:

```
select min(person_id), -- or MAX
   fruit_name 
from person_fruit
group by fruit_name;
```

This works in all DBMSes and not only in older MySQL version (I really like that MySQL finally follows standards, of course this will cause a lot of confusion for MySQL developers).

Answer (score 2):

You can't get distinct row based on single column as distinct provide unique based on all columns in your selection, instead you can use group by-

```
select person_id,fruit_name from person_fruit group by fruit_name;
```

Below query will provide you distinct rows based on combination of both columns.

```
select distinct person_id, fruit_name from person_fruit;
```

Comment: using group by fruit name leaving person_id will give error "not contained aggregate function"

Comment: No it won't @mohan111 MySQL allow that.

Comment: Perhaps depending on "compatibility mode"?

Comment: then how the result will come in MySQL ? which mango id it will pick if we are looking for distinct

Comment: Randomly... A real mess.

Comment: practically it will provide you first id (ascending order) but as per documentation it is not sure...you can use min or max function which id you want....if you need all columns based on that ordering then you can use of join....